# C# Active Directory - How can I load the "certificateTemplates" Property from an Enrollment Services directory object?

Tags: c#, active-directory, certificate, pki

I am trying to load details about the Microsoft PKI Issuing CAs from my AD Forest by iterating through the Enrollment Services AD container. One of the details that I'd like to include is the list of certificate templates enabled on each CA. In ADSIEdit, I can clearly see that there is a property named **certificateTemplates** in each Enrollment Services object which contains the information I need (please forgive all the redaction):

[image]

However, when I pull any of these objects into a .NET DirectoryEntry object, "certificateTemplates" is not one of the properties that is included by default. I discovered the [RefreshCache method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_RefreshCache_System_String___), which should allow you to pull in additional properties from a directory entry (so long as they exist on the entry), but this did not work for me:

```
DirectoryEntry EnrollmentServices = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{MyDC}/CN=Enrollment Services,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com");
DirectoryEntries CAs = EnrollmentServices.Children;
foreach(DirectoryEntry CA in CAs)
{
    object[] objectClass = (object[])CA.Properties[objectClassProperty].Value;
    if (objectClass[1].ToString() == @"pKIEnrollmentService")
    {
        CA.RefreshCache(new string[] { "certificateTemplates" });
        var Templates = CA.Properties["certificateTemplates"].Value;
        //Templates remains null
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered/resolved this issue before?

Comment: *"Templates remains null"* - is that true for every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @GabrielLuci - Haha! Good catch. The first CA in the collection truly has no templates assigned, but the very next one does. For the second one the property loads as expected. Thanks!

Also, thanks for helping me not get fired ;-)

Comment: Haha, no worries.... we all overlook the simple things sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RefreshCache()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_RefreshCache_System_String___) method does, in fact, correctly add the *certificateTemplates* property to each CA DirectoryEntry object. The first CA encountered in my loop simply has no templates assigned, which explains the null value for *Templates* in the first iteration of my foreach loop.

**Update:** If the certificateTemplates property contains only one entry, the property value will be a single string rather than an array containing only 1 element (thanks, Microsoft!). I use a try/catch to handle this edge case. If anyone has a more elegant approach, be my guest.

```
DirectoryEntry EnrollmentServices = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{MyDC}/CN=Enrollment Services,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com");
DirectoryEntries CAs = EnrollmentServices.Children;

List<string> templateNames;

foreach(DirectoryEntry CA in CAs)
{
    object[] objectClass = (object[])CA.Properties[objectClassProperty].Value;
    if (objectClass[1].ToString() == @"pKIEnrollmentService")
    {
        CA.RefreshCache(new string[] { "certificateTemplates" });
        object[] Templates;

        try
        {
            Templates = (object[])CAEntry.Properties[PropertyIndex.CertificateTemplates].Value;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            Templates = new object[] { CAEntry.Properties[PropertyIndex.CertificateTemplates].Value };
        }

        //I place the template names into a string list for ease of retrieval later.
        templateNames = new List<string>();
        if (Templates != null)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Templates.Length; x++) templateNames.Add(Templates[x].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```